# GNOME Shell extension problem when trying to install themes

Tags: 11.10, gnome, themes, gnome-tweak-tool

I want to install new themes on Ubuntu 11.10, so I went to the Internet and followed the instructions to how to install new themes. I've installed `gnome-tweak-tool`, the Ubuntu shell user extension and everything else that I needed. But after I installed everything and restarted GNOME Shell, I went into the Advanced Settings (GNOME Tweak Tool) and the shell extensions tab is blank like before the installation. Also, in the theme tab, the shell theme option it says could not list shell extensions.

Comment: Do you have the theme selector extension installed?

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure - Did the instructions you followed involve extracting the theme to /usr/share/themes? If not you can find a more detailed description of how to install a theme in 11.10 [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83851/can-i-use-gnome-3-themes-and-icons-with-unity-too/83879#83879)

Comment: wouldn't that be "/usr/share/gnome-shell/themes" instead, since he was referring to gnome-shell ?!

Answer (score 1):

there is only a temporary fix right now to make it work, since it is a bug!

first of all you need to create a hidden folder called .themes within your root folder.
`sudo su`          (type in your pwd)
`mkdir ~/.themes`  (creates the "hidden" .themes folder in your root directory)

now install the shell extension for gnome-tweak-tool:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme
```

install dconfEditor with ubuntu software center and put your theme folder of choice on your desktop, then copy it into the .themes folder like so:

```
sudo cp -r /home/username/Desktop/themeFolder ~/.themes
```

open up dconfEditor and browser through the tabs as followed:

> org > gnome > shell > extensions > user-theme
>   now type in your exact theme-name of the folder you copied into the .themes and into the values field of the right window.

after that is done you can open gnome-tweak-tool to chose your theme from the "> theme > shell theme" tab.

it is some work of course but it works for now.
you always can deactivate the extension of course from gnome-tweak-tool > shell extensions.