# Can I use GNOME 3 themes and icons with Unity too?

Tags: unity, gnome, themes, icons

I like to play around with themes and icons to make my desktop looking more lovely. Can I use the themes and icons also for Unity 3D/2D, or what do I have to look for to know when and how I have to use them?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61567/how-do-i-change-the-theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What themes you can use with Unity depends on the version of Ubuntu you are running.

- **Ubuntu 11.04 or earlier:** Use GTK+ 2 themes.
- **Ubuntu 11.10 or later:** Use GTK+ 3 themes.

If you are running Ubuntu 11.10 or later, you can use the same themes you would use with GNOME 3 (or, more accurately, GNOME Shell). This is because Unity itself is based on GNOME 3 in those versions. Unity in Ubuntu 11.04 and earlier is based on GNOME 2, so it uses a different set of themes.

Icon sets should be completely compatible with any Ubuntu release under any GNOME-based desktop environment (including Unity). Also, there should be no theme differences between Unity 3D and Unity 2D.

You can get themes and icon sets from sites like [gnome-look.org](http://gnome-look.org/) or [deviantART](http://www.deviantart.com/). After you download your desired theme sets, see [How do I change to a theme not listed in the Appearance screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61567/how-do-i-change-the-theme) or [How do I get and install more themes, icons, and pointers?](https://askubuntu.com/q/116/18612) for information on how to apply them.

Answer (score 3):

First, install GNOME Tweak Tool from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Once you download a theme or icon set you'll have to extract the theme or icon set and put it in the right folder. Use `gksu nautilus` to navigate to the downloaded file then right-click to extract the theme's tar or zip. Then, put that extracted folder in `/usr/share/themes` if it's a theme or `/usr/share/icons` if it's an icon set.  After that, open GNOME Tweak Tool and go from there.