# Package has unmet dependencies: gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme

Tags: gnome, repository, dependencies

I followed the instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75321/gnome-shell-extension-problem-when-trying-to-install-themes) but I got the following error when trying to install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme : Depends: gnome-shell-extensions-common but it is not going to be installed
```

Extra information:

Running Ubuntu with Gnome3

Answer (score 1):

gnome-shell-extensions-common depends upon gnome-shell-extensions, which already includes the user-theme extension, and so conflicts with the gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme package. There seems to be something wrong with the dependencies in that repository.

Anyway, you can simply install gnome-shell-extensions, which has the user theme extension. That's what I did and it worked.

Change themes using gnome-tweak-tool.

Answer (score 0):

In your Terminal, do this:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-common
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Didn't work, could you also tell me what that command should do? If I know what I'm doing I'll be able to formulate better questions. So far nearly every google source is "do this command, now this one" so I learn nothing at all. Thanks for the quick reply though...

Comment: hmm yeah :) , apt-get install -f will fix the broken pkg's(not successfully installed with dependencies issues also  ). so easily we can fix them up with this . so i have given that to you .

Comment: Okay, so it says this:
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 156 not upgraded.

The first time I ran it, it said something different (so it fixed something) but I still get the same error. Do I need to enter the commands from my link subsequently (in the same terminal session) or can I do it in separate sessions?

Comment: i have changed my answer , do it . i am sure that gonna help you .

Comment: I tried that one already but it still says the same thing :P So weird, maybe I need a reboot?

Comment: No need of a reboot. open synaptic and look for gnome-shell-extensions-common .

Comment: It's there, I'll mark it for reinstallation.

Answer (score 0):

You may force gnome-shell-extensions-common package version to be provided by the same PPA you're trying to install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme from. I'm wondering if you have different repos provide those packages in your sources...

Comment: So how would I do that (making sure they have the same repository/version)